# Определение города, региона посетителя сайта с записью в файл

Tags: php, javascript, ip

Имеется два рабочих скрипта.

Определяет ip, время,дату и т.д. посетителя сайта и вписывает отчёт в файл base.txt:

```
$file = fopen("base.txt","a+");
$ip = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
$time = date("H:i:s  d M Y");
$url_o = getenv(HTTP_REFERER);
$url_k = getenv(REQUEST_URI);
$soft = getenv(HTTP_USER_AGENT);
$all ="$ip   $time   $url_o   $url_k . \n";
fwrite($file,$all );
fclose($file);
```

Определяет регион, город посетителя сайта и вписывает в форму:

```
<script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
      jQuery("#user-city").val(ymaps.geolocation.city+', '+ymaps.geolocation.region+', '+ymaps.geolocation.country);
  }
</script> 
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type='text' name='city' id='user-city' value='' />
```

Возможно ли их объединить, чтобы в отчёт файла base.txt первого скрипта вписывались ещё и страна,регион, город посетителя сайта?

Answer (score 3):

На сайте ipgeobase.ru есть сервис, расположен по адресу: http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=******* .

В ответе содержится блок ip адресов, страна, город, регион, округ и координаты.

Посмотреть результат работы тут http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=85.114.175.250

Comment: Вариант с локальной базой ipgeobase https://github.com/rossvs/ipgeobase.php

Answer (score 0):

Объединить, конечно, же можно, но только теоретически,
потому что первый скрипт выполняется на сервере,
а второй на клиенте.

Вам же нужно чтобы всё выполнялось на сервере.

Поэтому вам нужно просто добавить библиотеку геолокации 
в вашу серверную инсталляцию и просто вызывать библиотеку,
которая определяет город по IP и сохранять эти данные.

Используйте, например, GeoIP Location:
* [http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php Geo IP Location] (англ.)

Answer (score 0):

Если нет возможности подключить на стороне сервера GeoIP Location, то как вариант, можно аяксом отправлять данные на сервер и уже сохранять php скриптом пришедшую информацию.

Comment: У вас есть готовый скрипт для осуществления этой идеи?